# How to access the OneToOne Field in template while submitting the form through CreateView class

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

```
Models.py


class LeadReminder(models.Model):
    first_reminder = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    second_reminder = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    third_reminder = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    remarks =  models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)


class LeadAdmin(models.Model):  
    admin_supporter_club_name =  models.CharField(max_length=240, blank=True, null=True) 
    leadreminder = models.OneToOneField(LeadReminder,    on_delete=models.CASCADE)



Views.py

class AdminCreateView(CreateView):
    fields=('admin_name_of_supporter_club')
    model = LeadAdmin
    template_name="Business_Dev/Business-admin-create.html"
    success_url='/business-admin/home/'



  (templates) Business-admin-create.html


  <form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}

   {{form.as_p}}
  </form>
```

How can i access the LeadReminder model fields in template while submitting the form via CreateView class in views. I am defining the LeadAdmin in the CreateView and LeadAdmin is connected to the LeadReminder through the OneToOneField.

As simply defining the fields of the LeadReminder in CreateView gives  error as I have defined the model LeadAdmin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly in your views.py you need to import your model.
Then in the views.py create a function, the example below is a very simple one(also assuming there is only one leadreminder) ....

```
def amendView(request):
    supporter = LeadAdmin.leadreminder(pk=1)
    return render(request, ' Business-admin-create.html', {'supporter':supporter})
```

Within the template you should then be able to use the variable supporter

Comment: I am using the class based view. Their is no need of making a separate function. Aso the create view don't have pk.

Comment: then within your class try...def amendView(self,request):
    supporter = LeadAdmin.leadreminder
    return self.render_to_response({'supporter':supporter})